# IntelliJ: how to navigate horizontally while in column mode

Tags: intellij-idea, editing

There are situations where column editing mode works great. One thing I'm finding a bit annoying right now though, is that I don't know how to skip to the left or right without editing while in column mode. Check the attached picture.

[image: editing some pre-formatted text so it fits an SQL insert statement]

So I've got some values in a matrix (copied from a select in DBVisualizer), and I want to add quotes and commas and stuff so it works as an SQL script. Currently my elongated cursor is positioned at the start of the "value2" column, and I want to skip to the end to add a quote there, a comma and another quote and then skip to the end of value3 and so on.

I get that I could do this another way - use regexp or do a better extraction of the text to start with. But now that I am where I am, I think there should be a way to navigate horizontally without losing the vertical selection that I've done. If I press left or right the selection collapses to a single line, same thing if I try ctrl-right (skip word).

Is there a key combo that does what I want in IntelliJ? If not, could I use some other tool (I'm on Ubuntu but if there's something in Windows that could work too)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IJ doesn't support that at the moment. However, huge multi-line editing improvements are planned for the next version (v.13, ETA is the end of 2013). Feel free to track [IDEA-80056](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056) progress.

Comment: I had a hunch that it wasn't available - that these features are on their way was even more than I was hoping for! Thanks. :)

Comment: Also some nice links to other products, and more awesome features being discussed under that link.